# How to load a RecyclerView with data from two or more tables SQLite

Tags: java, android

I am new to programming in Android and this is my first App. What I want is to enter the data from a table in a `Cardview` and the next `CardView` data from a different table, I tried to enter data into the method `onBindViewHolder` but do not have accomplished. This is what I tried to do:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder._info.setText(table1.get(position).getInfo());
        holder._seleccion.setText(table1.get(position).getSeletion());
        holder.tituloCV.setText(table1.get(position).getTittle_CV());
        holder.fondoCV.setImageResource(table1.get(position).getImage_CV());
        holder._logo.setImageResource(table1.get(position).getLogo_team());


        holder._info.setText(table2.get(position).getInfoTeam1());
        holder._seleccion.setText(table2.get(position).getSeletionTeam1());
        holder.tituloCV.setText(table2.get(position).getTittle_CV());
        holder.fondoCV.setImageResource(table2.get(position).getImage());
}

@Override public int getItemCount() { return size = (table1.size() + table2.size()); }
```

Just I put these two methods considering that is where data is entered into the views. I would appreciate any help that allows me to find a solution, thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 0):

I think, your adapter has List with data. It means that you should collect all data from DB to one List and pass to adapter.
Second option is to update adapter

```
adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
```

Comment: I can not join the two list on a list because each list has a different elements, then not be able to access the values to pass to the views of CardView as each will have different values.

Your second suggestion gives me the following problem, the method adapter.notifydatasetchanged (); returns the following error. Can not call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling

Comment: _I can not join the two list on a list because each list has a different elements, then not be able to access the values to pass to the views of CardView as each will have different values._ So probably you have a problem with architecture. You should pass object to adapter with all data which you want to show in RecyclerView or create another adapter but it means that you have to create new view.